# Should I trust an API that uses GET method for user auth?

Tags: api, rest, authentication, twitter-oauth, pastebin

I've been researching PASTEBIN type API's that would enable storage of code snippets for a project I'm working on. The problem is that most if the API's I've found do not support edit/update of existing pastes.

I found that the Snipt.org API does support snippet updates. However, authentication for the snipt.org API is done using your Twitter account. The snipt.org API docs (https://code.google.com/p/snipt-org/wiki/REST_API_Docs?tm=6#Authorization) suggest using a GET '/auth' call (providing a Twitter uname/password in the URL) to obtain an API token to access the API. Is it just me or does this seem like a good way to compromise your Twitter credentials?

I have used other sites that authenticate via Twitter, but I get authenticated on the Twitter site first which in turn sends a token to the authorized app.

Comment: "Should I trust an API" - No.

Comment: It doesn't really matter if it's using a `GET` or a `POST`, if someone is monitoring that HTTP traffic, they can see anything that goes across the wire.

Comment: @MikeChristensen https!

Comment: Understood, but I'm wondering why an API would proxy the twitter auth instead of just sending users to Twitter for oauth first.

Comment: @flup - HTTPS would apply equally to either `POST` or `GET`, as SSL runs before the HTTP layer.  An encrypted session is established, then the HTTP request is sent.

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but this sounds ten kinds of dubious.  Transmitting Twitter credential info in the clear?  Yuck.  I agree, sounds like a fantastic way to compromise your credentials.

Comment: as long as you don't actually use them for twitter .. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, obviously this API has some serious flaws.

But if you use https, the URLs of GET requests will get encrypted along the way. (But still get logged in the cache of your browser. do clear it.)

So if you really like snipt, you could use a new twitter account created simply for the purpose of authenticating to snipt.

It won't feel particularly good. And I have some serious doubts about the rest of their security code based on this part of the API. But I do not see how exactly your credentials could be stolen using this part of it by others than the snipt maintainers who already have access to your snipts. So if you protect only snipts with the credentials, and no tweets, you should be alright.